# I do not understand what 弱めんと means

Tags: particle-と

I am facing the following sentence 彼は痛みを弱めんと試みています。which sounds, more or less, "He's trying to lessen the distress (or the pain)". What's gonna puzzling me is the 弱めんと form which looks like a shortening (unknown to me). Any suggestions on what's behind it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Many thanks! It's an archaic expression, not a negation....

Comment: Era-specific wording or a dialect. With a bit more context I can help you.